# i'm having to restart the uwsgi process

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

i am using a combination of uwsgi and nginx to serve my flask app. what happens is that after a few hours (under very low load, < several hundred requests) the requests time out until i restart the uwsgi process and things work again for the same amount of time.

here is the nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen      3001;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location / { try_files $uri @myapp; }
    location @myapp {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/my/dir/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

my uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /my/dir

#python module to import
app = app
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /my/dir/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /my/dir/log/%n.log
~
```

how i launch the uwsgi process:

```
/my/dir/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /my/dir/uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: Did you manage to find out what was the problem with your setup. I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of ways in which your stack (expecially without concurrency as you have configured it) could hang.

i suggest you to investigate why instead of bypassing it (with features like harakiri). Enable the uWSGI tracebacker to understand what is going on when the app is stuck:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Tracebacker.html